Single Fault test how to measure voltage limits on accessible parts
I have question about the measuring setup for single fault testing. Here according the standard you need to make an fault on a component through short or open circuit or an overload. Then you have voltage limits on the accessible parts. When powering the device in this case 230 Vac and measuring with oscilloscope and probe, where I connect the reference (ground) of the probe to either neutral or phase line and the probe measuring side to the accessible port for instance RS485, I see a lot of noise or mains outlet signal. If I don't use isolation transformer the disturbance is on the phase line and when I use isolation transformer the disturbance splits on neutral and phase line.
At the moment, I use oscilloscope and then an network with resistor and capacitor which is called EN 60990 Bild 4 (BSM-500KK) where I measure current with instead of voltage limits.
How can I measure properly the voltage on accessible parts with powering device on (230 Vac) but not measure what comes from the grid? Sorry if this is basic question but there is no explanation what to use in the standard and cannot find it anywhere.
